# How to check a phonenumber that already added to the firestore database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Here in the Firestore databases is a collection called "Users", In that collection, there are 29 documents(States) and in each of that documents there are many collections(Districts). This collection includes many documents these documents include the user's data along with numbers).

so how do we check the phone number that has already been added to the database?

[image]

I write something like this

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        CollectionReference usersRef = firestore.collection("Users");

        String phoneNumber = "1234567890";
        

        usersRef.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                                for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                                    Object value = data.get(key);
                                    if (value instanceof String && ((String) value).equals(phoneNumber)) {

                                        isRealAvailable = true;


                                        Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "Number found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        // Phone number found
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            isRealAvailable = false;
                            Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "No number found, create an account!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                            // Handle error

                    }
                });
```

(the number is not a String value)
I don't know how to retrieve these details from different document names.

How do we get the Phone Number from the document? if it exists.

What I wanted is, I'm building a blood donors app, where people can register using their phone numbers. From different countries. So when a user sign-up with proper details, he can go to the main screen. Whenever he logout and login, he doesn't need to update the details again. As we know phone number login and signup are the same. Also, I want to separate the states and places in different documents and collections. I added the location permission and perspective codes so the country and states are chosen automatically. (will get the users location)

Answer (score 2):

When you're calling get() on the following collection reference:

```
CollectionReference usersRef = firestore.collection("Users");
```

It means that you're trying to get all user documents that exist in the `Users` collection. As soon as you get all users, you then check the `phoneNumber` against the one that you find in the database, which is bad since you'll need to pay for a document read even for the users that do not have that particular phone number. What you have to do instead is to create a query that should only return the documents that you are interested in.

On the other hand, your actual database schema isn't quite helping you to achieve that. In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. So if you need to get all users from Brooklyn / New York that have a particular phone number, I would recommend you have a schema that looks like this:

```
db
|
--- users (collection)
     |
     --- $uid (document)
          |
          --- city: "New York"
          |
          --- borough: "Brooklyn"
          |
          --- mobNumber: 720555
```

And in code, it should look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("users");
Query queryByMobNumber = usersRef.whereEqualTo("city", "New York")
                                 .whereEqualTo("borough", "Brooklyn")
                                 .whereEqualTo("mobNumber", 720555);
queryByMobNumber.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

So in Firestore, chaining multiple whereEqualTo calls will work perfectly fine.

Besides that, I see that you are changing a boolean value inside the callback, which will not be seen outside the callback because Firebase API is asynchronous. If you want to learn more about that, I recommend you check this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953). Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Comment: This is good I tried in that way, and I got want I wanted. But I need like this in the picture I posted. There are many documents in the collection "Users" and each documents contain States and in states there are many collections, that collection contains the users details. So i want to retrieve the mobNumber from that document. Is that possible ?

Comment: Using your actual database schema, no, it's not possible, unless you create a new schema where you can perform a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: What I wanted is, I'm building a blood donors app, where people can register using their phone number. From different countries. So when a user sign-up with proper details, he can go to the main screen. When ever he logout and login, he don't need to update the details again. As we know phone number login and signup are the same. Also, I want to separate the states and places in different documents and collections.
I added the location permission and perspective codes so the country and states are choosen automatically.(will get the users location)

Comment: I understand that, but using your database schema doesn't help you achieve that.

Comment: It's helpful I upvoted. But I need something like what I mentioned above. Will have to try a schema. Need to check the user who signed in early.